# Writing a CSV file in Java using OpenCSV

Tags: java, opencsv

[Edited] By editing my question, I have solved the problem. I just solved the problem by applying the following code to my method. I came to the decision to edit my old question. Because I have solved the problem.

```
 ****if (!file.exists())
            theRows.clear();****

@Repository
public class DatabaseImpl implements Database {

    List<String[]> theRows = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    public int insert(String tableName, List<String> values) {
        File file = new File(tableName + ".csv");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            prepareCsvFileAndInsertDataToCsvFile(values, file);
        } else {
            prepareCsvFileAndInsertDataToCsvFile(values, file);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private void prepareCsvFileAndInsertDataToCsvFile(List<String> values, File file) {
        if (!file.exists())
            theRows.clear();
        try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
            String[] header = new String[]{"id", "name", "surname", "age", "salary"};
            theRows.add(values.toArray(String[]::new));//arasdiracam
            writer.writeNext(header);
            writer.writeAll(theRows, false);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void update(String tableName, int rowId, List<String> values) {

    }

    @Override
    public List<String> select(String tableName, int rowId) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is better if you provide a question which shows the problem - and then you can post a separate answer which shows [how you solved your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). As it stands, it is going to be hard for anyone else to benefit from your solution, given it's not clear what _specific_ problem is actually being solved.

Comment: Also, make sure your solution is not solving a [duplicate problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=write+a+csv+file+using+opencsv+and+java+site%3Astackoverflow.com) for which there is already an answer.